# How to provide Host Key for Maven SSH usage in server.xml

Tags: maven, jsch, maven-wagon-plugin

In the Maven `settings.xml`, I want to define an SSH server and provide:

- The Host to connect to
- The user to connect to
- The location of a private key (to authenticate myself)
- Manually provide a Host Key (public key to verify the server)

I do not want:

- to depend on the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file
- to be asked to accept a host key
- to ignore the host key validation

As such, existing answers on StackExchange do not help me, which include:

- [Overridding the provider to the `NullKnownHostProvider` and setting `hostKeyChecking` to `no`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685988/how-to-avoid-maven-builds-stall-on-ssh-host-authenticity-problem?lq=1).
- [Manually executing ssh on the command line to get the hostkey entered in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323040/maven-wagon-scp-is-not-able-to-establish-a-connection).

This is an example of how I envisioned it could be setup in the maven `setup.xml`:

```xml
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>gitcloud.myserver.net:8001</id>
    <username>git</username>
    <privateKey>C:/data/home/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
    <configuration>
      <knownHostsProvider implementation="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.SingleKnownHostProvider">
        <hostKeyChecking>yes</hostKeyChecking>
        <contents>codecloud.web.att.com ssh-rsa XXXXA3NvvFakeSSHKEYsdfADA...doLQ==</contents>
      </knownHostsProvider>
    </configuration>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem, you can find many people on the Internet looking for a correct solution, trying to override the `knownHostsProvider` implementation with an instance of `SingleKnownHostsProvider`, as you explained in your example.

**First, here is why it's not so easy to do that:**

When the repository URL starts with `scp:`, Plexus, the component manager used by Maven, looks for a component with role `org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon` and hint `scp`, and find the only one that complies to these needs in the current Wagon implementation (up to 3.0.1 at least), that is of class `org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.ScpWagon`. This class extends the class `AbstractJschWagon` in the same package, and **this latter class statically defines a `file` role-hint to select a `KnownHostProvider`** instance.

Therefore, this `file` role-hint makes Plexus use the class `FileKnownHostsProvider` to instanciate a `KnownHostsProvider` object that is given to the `ScpWagon` instance. This is because the class `FileKnownHostsProvider` is defined the following way at the beginning of its source file:

```
public class FileKnownHostsProvider
[...]
* @plexus.component role="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.KnownHostsProvider"
*    role-hint="file"
```

On the contrary, the class `SingleKnownHostProvider` is **not** defined with role-hint `file` but with role-hint `single`:

```
public class SingleKnownHostProvider
[...]
* @plexus.component role="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.KnownHostsProvider"
*    role-hint="single"
```

**So, the binding to this unwanted (in your situation) `FileKnownHostsProvider` is statically defined in the `AbstractJschWagon` source file. This is the whole difficulty.**

**Now, here is how to solve the problem:**

Use this Maven wagon patched implementation [available here on GitHub](https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/maven-wagon), by running those steps:

1- in your `pom.xml`, you may have some maven extension defined this way:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

Note that you may use another version than the 3.0.1.

Anyway, change this definition by the specific version 3.0.1-SINGLE:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-SINGLE</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

2- This specific version `3.0.1-SINGLE` is a Wagon version I've patched to solve this very common problem, I've also encountered. It is not available on Maven central, but on GitHub.

So, you must install it yourself, the following way for instance:

```
% git clone https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/maven-wagon.git
% cd maven-wagon
% mvn install
```

3- Now, configure your `setup.xml` this way:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>gitcloud.myserver.net:8001</id>
    <username>git</username>
    <privateKey>C:/data/home/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
    <configuration>
      <hostKey>codecloud.web.att.com ssh-rsa XXXXA3NvvFakeSSHKEYsdfADA...doLQ==</hostKey>
    </configuration>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Everything should now work like you want: if the host key defined in the `setup.xml` file is correct, maven will not display the key fingerprint, nor ask you to validate this host key.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. Would love to see it merged with official implementation. Did you contact official maintainers?

Comment: I've not yet suggested them, but I will. Thanks.