# Using mvn release:prepare/perform with Git

Tags: git, maven, ssh, maven-release-plugin

I want to integrate Git with my Maven Workflow. Basically, I want to succesfully execute following 4 commands:

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:rollback
mvn release:perform
mvn deploy
```

This should work without any additional plugins or tools (no gitflow). I am at a loss pulling the documentation together, and am almost at a point where I want to declare that you would only use maven releases in combination with an svn repository.

My main problem seems to be in how to handle the server fingerprinting. I do not want (cannot) to use a password, so I need to revert to using publick/private key. I have put my public key already on the remote repository, and I seem to be able to authenticate with something similar to this:

```xml
<server>
  <id>giturl.com:1234</id>
  <username>git</username>
  <privateKey>C:/data/home/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
</server>
```

However, I seem not to be able to get past the server fingerprint checking. Some very vague and obscure sources seem to suggest that I can provide a `<server> <configuration> <knownHostsProvider>` section, but I seem not be able to get it right. I would expect that I can do something like this:

```xml
    <knownHostsProvider implementation="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.NullKnownHostProvider">
      <hostKeyChecking>no</hostKeyChecking>
    </knownHostsProvider>
```

I was expecting the hostkey checking to be ignored, but unfortunately my `mvn release:prepare` failed for that exact reason.

Should I give up, and revert back to svn to manage my regular maven releases? I am about to do exactly this ...

Comment: Where did you place the `<knownHostProvider>` block? Place it in a `<configuration>` inside `<server>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687946/1542723

Comment: That's what I did as I clumsily tried to explain.  Maybe issue affects only git?